# Can you bring Python debugger back to the original exception during custom exception handling?

Tags: python, exception, pdb

My code is raising a custom exception which is putting my debugger in the wrong place. For example in the following code, I would like to print the value of my `important_local_variable` from the debugger, however it seems to be inaccessable as the debugger is starting inside the `CustomException`:

**test.py**

```py
class CustomException(Exception):
    pass

def my_func():
    important_local_variable = 0
    badness = 1/important_local_variable

try:
    my_func()
except:
    raise CustomException
```

```
python3 -m ipdb test.py
bash-3.2$ python3 -m pdb test.py
> /Users/max/test.py(1)<module>()
-> class CustomException(Exception):
(Pdb)
```

Comment: It starts at the custom exception as thats the first line in your file. So it will read and define that class then move on to the rest of the code as it flows. What do you mean a way to bring it back to the original exception?

Comment: @ChrisDoyle in my toy example, the exception is caused by the `important_local_variable` being set to zero. I want a way to introspect this value in the debugger, currently I don't know how to do this

Comment: To give context for my question, in the real example that inspired my question, I am using custom exceptions to group errors into broad categories and surface them to the application. While this is working, it's broken my `pdb` debugging workflow, as I'm now no longer able to access the context of the original error

Comment: Can't you just pass the caught `Exception`  to `CustomException`? `except Exception as E: raise CustomException(E)`

Comment: Is there a reason you can't just insert a breakpoint with `import pdb;pdb.set_trace()` at the point that you want to stop?

Answer (score 1):

You may just need to adjust which stack frame you're in with `u` and `d` in pdb. In your toy example, once the `ZeroDivisionError` hits, you can go down into the function and pull out the local variable just fine:

```
C:\Users\Randy\test>python -m pdb test.py
> c:\users\randy\test\test.py(1)<module>()
-> class CustomException(Exception):
(Pdb) n
> c:\users\randy\test\test.py(4)<module>()
-> def my_func():
(Pdb) n
> c:\users\randy\test\test.py(8)<module>()
-> try:
(Pdb) n
> c:\users\randy\test\test.py(9)<module>()
-> my_func()
(Pdb) n
ZeroDivisionError: division by zero
> c:\users\randy\test\test.py(9)<module>()
-> my_func()
(Pdb) d
> c:\users\randy\test\test.py(6)my_func()
-> badness = 1/important_local_variable
(Pdb) important_local_variable
0
```

If it's the initial

```
> c:\users\randy\test\test.py(1)<module>()
-> class CustomException(Exception):
```

that was concerning you, that's just the interpreter running the code from the start, not the exception being triggered. This happens since we started pdb from the beginning of the program. You just need to step through the code with `n` until the errors start actually being thrown, as I did in the example above.

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is trying to define the exception class. You should let the debugger continue.

As per comment, it is the first line of the script.

Also even if you had a main function, the python control will start from first statement of module.

Comment: This is the right answer. At the commandline pdb pauses at the first line of code by default. Type `c` then hit enter to stop when the actual exception is raised and you can move up and down the stack there with `u` and `d`.